# pserve exits immediately after being launched in the VSCode python debugger

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-studio-code, pyramid

I have a python-2.7 env Pyramid 1.4 application that I've been developing on OS X (10.14.5 as of this writing).  Once the env is activated i can start pserve from the command line and test the app.  I want to be able to debug from within VSCode.  I've configured the debugger with the Pyramid setup in `launch.json`:

```
        {
            "name": "Python: Pyramid Application",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/development.ini"
            ],
            "pyramid": true,
            "jinja": true
        }
```

Whenever I start the Debugger from within VSCode (F5) all the expected commands run and they look legitimate:

```
$ source /my/app/path/env/bin/activate
$ cd /my/app/path ; env PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 /my/app/path/env/bin/python /my/home/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.4.12954/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 63836 /my/app/path/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py2.7.egg/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py /my/app/path/development.ini
```

There are no errors but the launcher command exits and the debugger never activates.  pserve is *not* running in the background.  the debugging toolbar briefly appears at the top of the editor window but then disappears after less than a second (so i imagine there's a brief debugging sessions that ends for some reason)

i've tried changing options in my development.ini to use a different pyramid server main

```
[server:main]
; use = egg:waitress#main
use = egg:pyramid#wsgiref
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 6666
```

no difference

there's very little information on the VSCode python pages.

I'd be fine adding code to the files i need to debug (my fallback is `pdb`) but would love to take advantage of the awesome debugger in VSCode.

Note that if i *manually* (instead of pressing F5) enter

```
 cd /my/app/path ; env PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 /my/app/path/env/bin/python /my/home/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.4.12954/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 63836 /my/app/path/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py2.7.egg/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py /my/app/path/development.ini
```

in the terminal - i get a `socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused` i assume because VSCode's debugger has already shut down.

if i run the following in the same VSCode terminal window

```
/my/app/path/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py2.7.egg/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py /my/app/path/development.ini
```

my server starts fine and serves requests.  so it seem like something to do with the ptvsd launcher.

any ideas?

Comment: immediately after writing this i realized that there is a subtle difference in how i run the app vs. how the debugger starts it.

the debugger starts using the `pserve.py` script directly but the way my application runs uses `pserve` which is itself a python script which wraps and configures `pserve.py`

so the problem has nothing to do with VSCode's debugger but rather with the debugger configuration.

i think the problem has something to do with : https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2427

Answer (score 2):

the solution i came up with (which works) is to change my pyramid setup in `launch.json` to looks like this:

```
        {
            "name": "Python: Pyramid Application",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/env/bin/pserve",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/development.ini"
            ],
            // "pyramid": true
            // "jinja": true
            "debugOptions": [
                "RedirectOutput",
            ]        
        }
```

basically i am forcing the debugger to launch pserve with a manual setup.  this works, i'm able to hit breakpoints and see variable values.